# Aggregate at 10 minutes for last 24 hours in db

Tags: sql-server, datetime

The following query splits given time range data into 5 minutes but it does this thing from start of timerange provided

```
With MNE
AS
(
SELECT *,DATEDIFF(dd,0,t.datetime) AS dayoffset,
DATEDIFF(ss,MIN(t.datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(dd,0,t.datetime)),t.datetime)/60 AS MinOffset
FROM cw.datas t
 WHERE t.DATETIME <= GETDATE()
 AND t.DATETIME > DATEADD(SECOND, -DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME),
 GETDATE()) % (60 * 5), DATEADD(DAY, - 1,GETDATE()))
)

SELECT  MIN(z.datetime) AS StartDatetime,
 MAX(z.datetime) AS ENdDatetime,
 sum(z.value) AS TotalSum
FROM MNE z
GROUP BY dayoffset,(MinOffset-1)/10
order by StartDatetime
```

With current time as `2020-09-14 12:28:43.793`, The output comes in following way :

```
StartDatetime,ENdDatetime,TotalSum
2020-09-13 12:25:03.000,    2020-09-13 12:31:00.000,    63763.51
2020-09-13 12:31:03.000,    2020-09-13 12:36:00.000,    48348.34
2020-09-13 12:36:03.000,    2020-09-13 12:41:00.000,    54387.69
--
--
2020-09-14 12:16:00.000,    2020-09-14 12:20:57.000,    54353.72
2020-09-14 12:21:00.000,    2020-09-14 12:25:57.000,    53780.48
2020-09-14 12:26:00.000,    2020-09-14 12:28:42.000,    25328.56
```

I want aggregation of split from current timestamp i.e. `2020-09-14 12:28:43.793` back to last 24 hours.

```
Expected result :

StartDatetime,ENdDatetime,TotalSum
--
--
2020-09-14 11:58:43.000,    2020-09-14 12:08:43.000,    354654
2020-09-14 12:08:43.000,    2020-09-14 12:18:43.000,    354353
2020-09-14 12:18:43.000,    2020-09-14 12:28:43.000,    354665
```

Help appreciated.

Sample Data :

```
datas

datetime,   abc,    def,    ghi,    value
2020-09-11 12:22:36.000,    AYSH,   mains,  SAE,    363.12
2020-09-11 12:22:39.000,    AYSH,   mains,  SAE,    358.2
2020-09-11 12:22:42.000,    AYSH,   mains,  SAE,    353.66
2020-09-11 12:22:45.000,    AYSH,   mains,  SAE,    349.14
2020-09-11 12:22:48.000,    AYSH,   mains,  SAE,    344.84
2020-09-11 12:22:51.000,    AYSH,   mains,  SAE,    340.63
2020-09-11 12:22:54.000,    AYSH,   mains,  SAE,    336.45
```

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result?

Comment: @Vernou given the sample data

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide table definitions for `cw.datas` so I cannot apply my solution to your query.

This recursive CTE generates the 144 intervals with duration of 10 minutes starting from now and going back 24 hours.

```
with stamps as
(
  select getdate() as Stamp, 0 as Interval
    union all
  select dateadd(MI, -10, s.Stamp), s.Interval+1
  from stamps s
  where s.Interval < 144 -- 24 hours * 6 10-minute intervals = 144 10-minute intervals
)
select s.Stamp as FromDateTime,
       dateadd(MI, 10, s.Stamp) as ToDateTime,
       s.Interval
from stamps s
order by s.Stamp
option(maxrecursion 144);
```

Output looks like:

```
FromDateTime                ToDateTime                  Interval
--------------------------- --------------------------- ---------
2020-09-13 14:00:54.740     2020-09-13 14:10:54.740     144
2020-09-13 14:10:54.740     2020-09-13 14:20:54.740     143
2020-09-13 14:20:54.740     2020-09-13 14:30:54.740     142
2020-09-13 14:30:54.740     2020-09-13 14:40:54.740     141
2020-09-13 14:40:54.740     2020-09-13 14:50:54.740     140
... 
2020-09-14 13:10:54.740     2020-09-14 13:20:54.740     5
2020-09-14 13:20:54.740     2020-09-14 13:30:54.740     4
2020-09-14 13:30:54.740     2020-09-14 13:40:54.740     3
2020-09-14 13:40:54.740     2020-09-14 13:50:54.740     2
2020-09-14 13:50:54.740     2020-09-14 14:00:54.740     1
2020-09-14 14:00:54.740     2020-09-14 14:10:54.740     0
```

[Fiddle 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=98169304014ea7bbb640f19ad164d4dc)

---

Combination with the given sample data.

**Sample data**

```
create table data
(
  stamp datetime,
  abc nvarchar(4),
  def nvarchar(5),
  ghi nvarchar(3),
  value decimal(10,2)
);

insert into data (stamp, abc, def, ghi, value) values
('2020-09-11 12:22:36.000', 'AYSH', 'mains', 'SAE', 363.12),
('2020-09-11 12:22:39.000', 'AYSH', 'mains', 'SAE', 358.2 ),
('2020-09-11 12:22:42.000', 'AYSH', 'mains', 'SAE', 353.66),
('2020-09-11 12:22:45.000', 'AYSH', 'mains', 'SAE', 349.14),
('2020-09-11 12:22:48.000', 'AYSH', 'mains', 'SAE', 344.84),
('2020-09-11 12:22:51.000', 'AYSH', 'mains', 'SAE', 340.63),
('2020-09-11 12:22:54.000', 'AYSH', 'mains', 'SAE', 336.45);
```

**Solution**

Defines a reference datetime because `getdate()` would produce few results with sample data for `2020-09-11`.

```
declare @refStamp datetime = '2020-09-12 00:00:00.000'; -- replacement for getdate()

with stamps as
(
  select @refStamp as FromDateTime,
         dateadd(MI,10,@refStamp) as ToDateTime,
         0 as Interval
    union all
  select dateadd(MI, -10, s.FromDateTime),
         s.FromDateTime,
         s.Interval+1
  from stamps s
  where s.Interval < 144 -- 24 hours * 6 10-minute intervals = 144 10-minute intervals
)
select s.FromDateTime,
       s.ToDateTime,
       d.abc,
       sum(d.value) as SumValues
from stamps s
left join data d
  on  d.stamp >= s.FromDateTime              -- greater than or equal to FromDateTime
  and d.stamp <  s.ToDateTime                -- smaller than ToDateTime
where s.FromDateTime >= '2020-09-11 12:00:00.000'   -- limit output results (part 1)
  and s.FromDateTime <= '2020-09-11 13:00:00.000'   -- limit output results (part 2)
group by s.FromDateTime, s.ToDateTime, d.abc
order by s.FromDateTime
option(maxrecursion 144);
```

**Result**

```
FromDateTime             ToDateTime               abc   SumValues
------------------------ ------------------------ ----- ----------
2020-09-11 12:00:00.000  2020-09-11 12:10:00.000  NULL  NULL
2020-09-11 12:10:00.000  2020-09-11 12:20:00.000  NULL  NULL
2020-09-11 12:20:00.000  2020-09-11 12:30:00.000  AYSH  2446.04
2020-09-11 12:30:00.000  2020-09-11 12:40:00.000  NULL  NULL
2020-09-11 12:40:00.000  2020-09-11 12:50:00.000  NULL  NULL
2020-09-11 12:50:00.000  2020-09-11 13:00:00.000  NULL  NULL
2020-09-11 13:00:00.000  2020-09-11 13:10:00.000  NULL  NULL
```

[Fiddle 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6e01d218b6ebca2157acc2df61ddf616)

Comment: Thanks for above fiddle,You have generated correctly the intervals.The thing i want aggrgation in these intevals in existing table which have data at seconds interval.Consider sample above

Comment: @Arshanvit, solution expanded to perform aggregation over sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is dense then it's really not necessary to use the recursive query. Just compute the number of seconds elapsed since `startTime`. And this form lets you easily adjust the range start and size of the interval.

```
with timeRelatedFields as (
    select
        dateadd(hour, -24,
            dateadd(millisecond, -datepart(millisecond, getdate()), 
                getdate())) as startTime,
        600 as intervalSeconds
), tableTimeRelatedFields as (   
    select *,
        d.value as consideredValue,
        datediff(second, st.startTime, d."datetime") / intervalSeconds as interval
    from cw.datas as d cross apply timeRelatedFields as st
    where d."datetime" >= startTime and d."datetime" < getdate()
)
select
    dateadd(second, intervalSeconds *  interval,      startTime) as StartDateTime,
    dateadd(second, intervalSeconds * (interval + 1), startTime) as EndDateTime,
    sum(consideredValue) as TotalSum      
from tableTimeRelatedFields
group by interval;
```

Comment: Kindly limit it to current timestamp as currently it is going to last timestamp of day and actual question is to get to current  timestamp only and for last 24 hours. Also ```dateadd(second, intervalSeconds *  interval,      startTime) as StartDateTime,
    dateadd(second, intervalSeconds * (interval + 1), startTime) as EndDateTime```, the following fields  ```intervalSeconds``` and  ```startTime``` are inaccessible.